# Does path for filepicker.io uploads have to consist of existing folders?

Tags: filepicker.io

If I try to upload a file to S3 with something like `path=/customer123/inquiry987/` and those folders don't already exist in our S3 bucket, will the upload fail or will the folders be automagically created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folders will be automatically created.